# adding additional value to existing value of an inputfield on click - jQuery

Tags: jquery, click

i got this inputfield with tag buttons

```
<input id="demooutput" type="text" size="15" value="My Text" name="demo" />
<span class="demooutput">
    <a href="#" class="button orange"> A</a>
    <a href="#" class="button orange"> B</a>
    <a href="#" class="button orange"> C</a>
    <a href="#" class="button orange"> D</a>
    <a href="#" class="button orange"> E</a>        
</span>
```

with this jQuery code i add the values to the input

```
$('.demooutput a').click(function(){
    $('#demooutput').val($(this).html());
    return false;
});
```

but i clear my existing value with every click on the button

i want to add the value from the button additionally to the existing value from input

Example who i want it

```
My Text A (by click on A)
My Text A B (by click on A and B)
My Text B C E (by click on B, C and E)
and so on..
```

See a Demo on **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/aJPrG/)**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$('#demooutput').val($('#demooutput').val() + $(this).html());

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$('.demooutput a').click(function(){
    var values = $('#demooutput').val().split(' ');
    values.push($(this).html());
    $('#demooutput').val(values.join(' '));
    return false;
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/aJPrG/1/)

Or just simply:

```
$('.demooutput a').click(function(){
    $('#demooutput').val($('#demooutput').val() + ' '+ $(this).html());
    return false;
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/aJPrG/2/)

The first approach is recommended in some cases though, as it separates the logic clearly. For example: if you need to toggle the text (click 'A' and then click 'A' again to hide 'A', just to remove 'A' from the array and join)

Answer (score 1):

This isn't tested code, but you're looking for something like this.

```
$('.demooutput a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); // jQuery for return false
    var $demooutput = $('#demooutput'); // cache selector for performance
    $demooutput.val($demooutput.val()+' '+$(this).html());
});
```